# Cordova: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.plugins.toast')

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am currently working on a Cordova application and attempting to integrate a toast message feature using the cordova-plugin-x-toast package from [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-toast). However, I encountered an error when invoking the plugin within the function.

```
TypeError: **undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.plugins.toast')**
```

Please help me to resoleve this issue.

I attempted to integrate the toast message feature into my Cordova application using the cordova-plugin-x-toast package from [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-toast). I was expecting the toast messages to display as intended, but unfortunately, I encountered an error when trying to invoke the plugin within the function.